# Is $p(x)=(5/12)^x + (12/13)^x - 1$ strictly increasing function?

Tags: calculus

I tried with , whenever $x > y$ implies $p(x) - p(y) =( 5/13)^x (1-(13/5)^{(x-y)}) + (12/13)^x (1- (13/12)^{(x-y)}) > 0 $.
But here I don't understand why the answer is no.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is in fact strictly decreasing. Note that $\frac{5}{12}$ and $\frac{12}{13}$ are both less than $1$, and so $\left(\frac{5}{12}\right)^x$ and $\left(\frac{12}{13}\right)^x$ are both strictly decreasing. This implies that their sum is strictly decreasing; the constant term in $p(x)$ is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

> But here I don't understand why the answer is no.

You started with
$$p(x) - p(y) =\left( \frac{5}{13}\right)^x \left( 1-\left( \frac{13}{5}\right)^{x-y}\right) + \left( \frac{12}{13}\right)^x\left(1- \left( \frac{13}{12}\right)^{x-y}\right) 
$$
which is correct so far. But that expression is *negative* for $x > y$, not positive, because
$$
\left( \frac{13}{5}\right)^{x-y} > 1 \implies 1-\left( \frac{13}{5}\right)^{x-y} < 0 \\
\left( \frac{13}{12}\right)^{x-y} > 1 \implies 1-\left( \frac{13}{12}\right)^{x-y} < 0
$$

Therefore $p$ is *decreasing.*

Answer (score 1):

We have $p(x)=a^x+b^x -1$ with $0< a,b<1.$

Then $p'(x)= a^x \ln a +b^x \ln b$. Since $ \ln a , \ln b<0$, $p'(x)<0.$

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to show that $y=a^x$ , $0<a<1$, is strictly decreasing(why?)

Set $e^{-b}:=a$, $b>0$.

$y= e^{-bx}$ is strictly decreasing since

$y'(x)=( -b)e^{-bx} <0$, $x$ real.